# How can I extract int and float from a string in C language?

Tags: c, string, parsing, readfile, text-parsing

I am a beginner of C language, and I encounter some problem in doing exercise.
This is the requirement of my task:

I need write a C program to read data from a text file. In the file, there are many lines and each line has at most 3 digits: `a`, `b`, `c`. The three digits hold different information of a user.
For example:
[image]

Every number is separated by a space. As you see in the picture, it is possible that there are only 1 or 2 digits in a line. (In other words, some users don't have `b` and `c`).

My solution is that:
Using `while` loop and `fgets` to obtain all digit in each line and hold them in a buffer string.

My problem is that:
I don't know how to extract the integer and float numbers from the string respectively.
Also, it is difficult to handle the situation that there is only `a` and `b` but `c` is not existed.

Comment: `sscanf`? Works the same as regular scanf (see any introduction to C), except it takes its input from a string. Its return value will tell you how many items it got.

Comment: The float can be in any position, or just the third in the line?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: I am very sorry about this. It is my first time for using stack over flow, thank you for your hint!!

Comment: YES!!!! I slove it!! thx!!